# docker-compose image named: "prefix_%s_1" instead of "%s"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I set up a couple of Docker containers in `docker-compose.yaml` file with links, the name of the containers ends up being of the format `prefix_%s_1` instead of `%s`, and the alias in `/etc/hosts` on the linking container is the same.

**Why is the alias of the `redis` container `test_redis_1` instead of `redis`?**

Here are the relevant files and output:

```
# docker-compose.yaml
monkey:
    build: ../../monkey
    dockerfile: test.Dockerfile
    links:
      - redis:redis
    ports:
      - "9006:9006"

redis:
    build: ../storage/redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

After running `docker-compose build && docker-compose up`:

```
$ docker-compose ps
Name           Command                        State  Ports
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
test_redis_1   redis-server /usr/local/et ...   Up   0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp
test_monkey_1  python -m SimpleHTTPServer ...   Up   0.0.0.0:9006->9006/tcp
```

Output from the `test_monkey_1` container:

```
Step 14 : RUN cat /etc/hosts
 ---> Running in 1c104e3d9bf5
172.17.1.26     75a485df1325
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.1.26     thirsty_lumiere.bridge
172.17.0.220    test_redis_1
172.17.0.220    test_redis_1.bridge
172.17.1.26     thirsty_lumiere
 ---> 3a06bac9b3ca
Removing intermediate container 1c104e3d9bf5
Step 15 : RUN echo
 ---> Running in a1c5b5f8ae0f

 ---> 385c9ee44332
Removing intermediate container a1c5b5f8ae0f
Step 16 : RUN ifconfig eth0 | grep inet addr
 ---> Running in 17cd638c6473
          inet addr:172.17.1.28  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
 ---> 21235e29abc1
Removing intermediate container 17cd638c6473
Step 17 : RUN echo
 ---> Running in 8c0b1db2a69b

 ---> e2dd190eb4d1
Removing intermediate container 8c0b1db2a69b
Step 18 : RUN env
 ---> Running in 50cd1b6bf9da
HOSTNAME=75a485df1325
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/data/web/tunnelbear.com/play/tPWD=/data/web/tunnelbear.com/root
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Answer (score 70):

According to [docker compose issue #745](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/745):

> By default, Compose bases the project name on basename of the
>   directory compose commands are run from. The project name can be
>   overridden either by passing a -p / --project-name option for each
>   command or setting the COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME environment variable.

You can set the prefix of your choice to your container names by writing something like this:

```bash
$ docker-compose -p MY_PROJECT_NAME
```

which is the equivalent to (the more readable):

```
$ docker-compose --project-name MY_PROJECT_NAME
```

Comment: I tried -p param and not working `docker-compose -p '' up -d` - I want to set it empty

Comment: But this will work `docker-compose -p 'somePrefix' up -d` i.e. not empty value only

Comment: @NamGVU It's not possible to pass empty project name like that. See: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1621#issuecomment-118210322

Comment: make sure to use lower case names or it gives error of invalid project name

Comment: Now you can also declare your project name in the docker-compose.yml file, using the name property (see https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/schema/compose-spec.json#L14).

Answer (score 38):

You could just set container name to what you want via `container_name`:

```
redis:
    build: ../storage/redis
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

And container hostname could also be set via `hostname`.

Comment: The actual behavior is that compose will add both prefix and suffix

Comment: to add to this: the prefix is only added if using RUN, not with UP

Comment: Nice idea but this works only for single instances i.e., without scaling. If you do `docker-compose scale redis=3`, `container_name` will not work. `container_name` is hard coded to a single instance .Source: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3722

Comment: @vadasambar ... which makes perfect sense, because that very counter is automatically appended to distinquish the exact container instance while scaling.

Answer (score 15):

Docker compose will use the name of the directory with your compose file as the name of the project unless you set if via the [-p option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/)

```
-p, --project-name NAME     Specify an alternate project name (default: directory name)
```

Compose supports declaring [default environment variables in an environment file named .env](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/) placed in the folder where the docker-compose command is executed (current working directory).

Where you'll want to set [COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/)

Answer (score 13):

That's just how docker-compose names containers so that it can manage them.

The basename is the name of the directory containing the `docker-compose.yaml` file.  This is followed by the name of the container as specified in your `docker-compose.yaml` file, and finally that is followed by an instance number which increases if you bring up multiple instances of a container using something like `docker-compose scale`.

This naming scheme is how docker-compose is able to identify your containers when you attempt to operate on them using something like `docker-compose stop`.

I don't think this conflicts with the documentation in any way.  That is, if I start with, say, this `docker-compose.yaml` in a directory named `sotest`:

```
irc:
  image: docker.io/xena/elemental-ircd
  links:
    - web

web:
  image: larsks/thttpd
```

And then bring up the compose:

```
$ docker-compose up
```

I get two containers:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                           ...NAMES
960c1491c03e        docker.io/xena/elemental-ircd   ...sotest_irc_1
422bba313e71        larsks/thttpd                   ...sotest_web_1
```

If I look at the `/etc/hosts` file inside of `sotest_irc_1`, I see:

```
172.17.0.28 web 422bba313e71 sotest_web_1
```

In addition to a number of other names.  So the linked host is
available by name as described in the docs.

Comment: Doesn't this conflict with what the documentation says? (https://docs.docker.com/compose/yml/#links). The `/etc/hosts` file in the doc's example has `%s` instead of `prefix_%s_1`.

Comment: I don't know; which part of the documentation are you looking at?

Comment: Is your original *Output from the test_monkey_1 container* the `docker exec` output or the `docker build` output? Have you tested `docker exec` or `docker-compose run`?

Answer (score 1):

the ways

### A. define in dockerfile

at top level of dockerfile

```yaml
name: proj_name
```

//seems not exactly same with other way

- this way not show services which has same prefix but in other dir

### B. define in .env

`.env` at same dir of dockerfile

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=proj_name
```

//same effect with `-p` way

- show all services which has same prefix (even in other dir)

### C. specify in compose cli

//the way they mentioned.

-p, --project-name string

```bash
docker compose --project-name proj_name
```

---

refs:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/envvars/#compose_project_name
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2982#issuecomment-285040554