# docker-compose: remove default suffix on container name?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

**my.yml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  myservice:
    image: myimage
```

When I run `docker-compose -p myprefix -f my.yml up`

It creates container named `myprefix_myservice_1`.

**Is it possible to generate name, so it would use prefix (project name) and service name only without suffix?**

**In this case it should be:** `myprefix_myservice`

Whats the point of `_1` suffix anyway? Looks weird and does not seem to do anything important, like incrementing `_2` for new container etc? If I run same prefix/service name, it just gonna start existing container anyway. So really don't see any reason to have all containers contain same `_1` suffix.

I could use `container_name`, but then it won't be possible to reuse same compose file for multiple containers.

P.S. I read this question: [docker-compose image named: "prefix_%s_1" instead of "%s"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045358/docker-compose-image-named-prefix-s-1-instead-of-s)

But it does not give any answer about suffix.

Comment: The `_1` actually appear there because the `docker-compose` file would be the same in order to run a swarm of containers, so it would matter as soon as [`replicas`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#replicas) are concerned.

Comment: But im not running swarm and using replicas. I want my containers to have different names anyway, because it would be easier to distinguish than some counter.

Comment: Yes I totally got this from your question but the file and its specification are the same, whether you use compose or swarm on it.

Comment: Its silly that there is no way to properly control name you want. You can specify prefix, but not suffix:)

Comment: For most practical purposes, you can use `docker-compose` commands using the Compose service name; for example, `docker-compose stop myservice`.  If you do that then you don't really care at all what the container name is.

Comment: I do care, because there will be multiple containers. And I need to distinguish them properly. Yes they would be stopped like that, but name should be unique and following my pattern, not some forces _1 suffix:)

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way to do it that works in non-Swarm mode using [variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#substitute-environment-variables-in-compose-files) and `container_name`:

```yaml
# my.yml
version: '3'
services:
  myservice:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: ${MYPREFIX}_myservice_${MYSUFFIX}
```

```
$ MYPREFIX=prefix MYSUFFIX=test docker-compose -f my.yml up
...
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
def6d2925819        redis:alpine        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        6379/tcp            prefix_myservice_test
```

Comment: I actually mentioned container_name, saying its not good option, because then you cant reuse project name and service name.

Comment: @Andrius What you mean reuse? Each container name will have to be unique. If you want to run `docker compose -f my.yml up` multiple times, you're going to need those suffixes anyway.

Comment: Unique, but you can use different prefix/project name to make it unique. So thats why I dont care about suffix. And that sufffix is static if you dont use swarm, meaning it does nothing to preserve uniqueness. Thats why I want to get rid of it.

Comment: @Andrius I think I understand what you're trying to do. Check out the edited answer. You can template the container_name with any variables you want.

Comment: Hm, it looks like it does not do what I expected. It does not create new container, if you specify different prefix. It just renames existing one. I was expecting to work same way as when you define project name with `-p` -> so new container would be set with such prefix.

`user@user:~/tmp/docker-samples$ PROJECT_NAME=test docker-compose -f postgres.yml up -d
Starting test_postgres ... done
user@user:~/tmp/docker-samples$ PROJECT_NAME=test2 docker-compose -f postgres.yml up -d
Recreating test_postgres ... done`

Comment: @Andrius You can combine the concepts such as ` MYPREFIX=prefix10 MYSUFFIX=test docker-compose -p "$MYPREFIX" -f my.yml up` You can also use a tool like `sed` or `envsubst` on the compose file itself. I would suggest opening a new question if you still need help with that as it doesn't really relate to controlling the container suffix.

Comment: As I have written it does relate. With container_name prefix, it works even worse, because it just uses one container, not creating new (if prefix is different), meaning such workaround is useless (at least for managing multilpe containers). It the same thing as using `container_name` without custom prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Now I can use this:

```yaml
version: '3'
name: myprefix # this is project name instead of `-p` option
services:
  myservice:
    image: myimage
    container_name: '${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_myservice'
```

I searched but there's no way to get service name in yaml from my understand.
We may have to use env variable or type `myservice` twice for name prop.

Answer (score 0):

Docker compose supports scaled services:

```yaml
services:
  test:
    image: nginx:latest
    scale: 2
```

```bash
docker compose up -d
❯ docker compose up -d
[+] Running 2/2
 ✔ Container tmp-test-2  Started                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.5s 
 ✔ Container tmp-test-1  Started
```

You can manually set the number of instances for a service:

```bash
❯ docker compose up --scale test=3 --detach
[+] Running 3/3
 ✔ Container tmp-test-1  Started                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.4s 
 ✔ Container tmp-test-2  Started                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.6s 
 ✔ Container tmp-test-3  Started
```

Interestingly `docker compose` vs `docker-compose` separates with dashes rather than underscores.

When using other compose commands, there is an optional `--index` parameter that can target the replica you want. e.g.

```bash
docker compose exec --index 2 test hostname
```

Anyway. Hope this helps.