# How to know the names of all containers spun up by `docker-compose up`?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I'm tasked with creating a utility that spins up docker containers -- by calling `docker-compose up --detach` -- then checks the exit-codes of all those containers.

I'm starting by doing manually what I think the utility will do, and using very simple Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml examples:

My Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml are as follows:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM alpine:3.15 as base
```

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.6'
services:
  dummy:
    build:
      context: .
    entrypoint: ["sh", "-c", "exit 42"]
```

```
$ docker-compose up --build --detach
WARNING: The Docker Engine you're using is running in swarm mode.

Compose does not use swarm mode to deploy services to multiple nodes in a swarm. All containers will be scheduled on the current node.

To deploy your application across the swarm, use `docker stack deploy`.

Building dummy
[+] Building 0.3s (5/5) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                          0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 43B                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:3.15                                0.0s
 => CACHED [1/1] FROM docker.io/library/alpine:3.15                                           0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                        0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                       0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:35e223a20dbce8c0b81d3257f8cad0c7b2b35d8e18eadfec7eeb7de86a472e7b  0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/docker-compose_dummy                                       0.0s
Successfully built 35e223a20dbce8c0b81d3257f8cad0c7b2b35d8e18eadfec7eeb7de86a472e7b
Starting docker-compose_dummy_1 ... done
$
$ docker inspect docker-compose_dummy_1 --format='{{.State.ExitCode}}'
42
$
```

**Question: Is there a way to know the names of all the containers spun up by `docker-compose up` as would seem required for the subsequent `docker inspect`?

Note: it is within my utility's ability to set environment variables, but it cannot create or modify a .env or the docker-compose.yml.**

From recent reading ([docker-compose image named: "prefix_%s_1" instead of "%s"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045358/docker-compose-image-named-prefix-s-1-instead-of-s)), I understand that the "prefix" to the service is controllable with `--project-name` and defaults to `basename $PWD`.

And from [Docker-compose: why does the number appended to services not increment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71312377/docker-compose-why-does-the-number-appended-to-services-not-increment), I understand that the suffixed number increments with `--scale`.

But I'm having a hard time putting this all together into a whole: so given an immutable `docker-compose.yml`, `Dockerfile`, and `.env`, is there a way I can determine the names of all containers spun up by `docker-compose up --detach` that I can then use with `docker inspect ... --format='{{.State.ExitCode}}'` to determine each's exit code?

(I'm most unsure about that suffixed integer. I don't think my utility will be using the `--scale` argument, but I'm not sure if there are other reasons that suffixed number could be anything other than "_1", so I'm dubious about assuming that the suffix will be "_1")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you already tried this ?

```
docker-compose ps -a
```

Comment: That looks promising -- I will experiment with it to understand it further. Output format seems to be an ascii table -- is there a way to get structured output like json/yaml/xml?